# How to set style(small and large) to Button programmable way?

Tags: android

How to set style(small and large) to Button programmable way ?

Is it possible ?

I can set the style to the Button from xml resource (like styte= ?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall).
But I don't know how set it programmable way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to change button style when runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a style at runtime, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like that:

```
Button button = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
```